# Pythonic way of importing 'complex' script result to another script

Tags: python, module, python-import

This is probably going to be flagged as duplicate as I went through a lot of post on that matter, but I really need help for that particular example.

So let say that I have a main script built for plotting some data, and then a few other scripts that I would like to import into that main plotting script in order, well, to retrieve those data.

I found that the most pythonic way of doing so is to import the script and then use it like a module, but since I am pretty new to Python I can't figure out how to properly do it with those pieces of code.
I use code written by someone else and adapted to fit my purpose so that might be an issue too.
I wanted to save some resources and avoid to write and read files to disk for every step so that is why I want to extract the data within my plotting script and have my pandas panel available in memory for plotting purpose.

Ideally my master_plot.py would look like that:

```
#functions for the plotting part

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import Tab

    data= Tab.main(some_path) #this script would calculate tab and return a pd.panel that will be used by the plotting section
    plot(data)
```

Now for the actual tab script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class SubDomains( object ):
    '''
    a class that reads in and prepares a dataset to be used in masking
    '''
    def __init__( self, fiona_shape, rasterio_raster, id_field, **kwargs ):
        #do stuff
    @staticmethod
    def rasterize_subdomains( fiona_shape, rasterio_raster, id_field ):

        from rasterio.features import rasterize
        import six
        import numpy as np

        #do stuff
    def _domains_name( self, fiona_shape, rasterio_raster, **kwargs ):
        #do stuff
    def _domains_generator( self, **kwargs ):

        #do stuff

def extract_tab( filelist, subdomains_arr ):
    '''
    extract the number of burned pixels across subdomains
    '''
    def read_firescar( x ):
        #do stuff

    def tab_counts( x ):
        #do stuff

    def get_year_fn( x ):
        #do stuff


    return pd.DataFrame( rep_arr ).T

def tab_processing(maps_path):

    l = pd.Series( sorted( glob.glob( os.path.join( maps_path, 'FireScar*.tif' ) ) ) )

    # now lets groupby the repnum by splitting the filenames with a function
    def get_rep_fn( x ):
        ''' function to split the repnum out of an ALF output filename '''
        return os.path.basename( x ).split( '_' )[ 1 ]

    rep_groups = l.groupby( l.map( get_rep_fn ) )

    # initialize a SubDomains object 
    sub_domains = SubDomains( shp, rasterio.open( l[0] ), 'Id' )

    # now extract the newly rasterized sub domains numpy array
    subdomains_arr = sub_domains.sub_domains

    pool = mp.Pool( 32 )
    out = pool.map( lambda x: extract_tab( x, subdomains_arr ), [ group.tolist() for rep_num, group in rep_groups ] )
    pool.close()

    # now there is a list of pd.DataFrame objects that we can collapse into a single 3-D pd.Panel
    rep_list = sorted( [ int(rep_num) for rep_num, group in rep_groups ] )
    year_list = sorted( out[0].index.astype(int) )
    # rep_list = np.repeat( rep_list, len(year_list) )
    # year_list = np.array([year_list for i in range(len(rep_list)) ]).ravel()

    tab_panel = pd.Panel( { i:j for i,j in zip(rep_list, out) } )
    return tab_panel

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import os, sys, re, rasterio, glob, fiona, shapely
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from pathos import multiprocessing as mp
    from collections import defaultdict

    path = sys.argv[1]
    tab_processing(path)
```

This script was a standalone before so I am not sure if the best way would be to call subprocess or if it could still be used as a module. One of the issue with this exact version is `global name 'pd' is not defined` which makes sense, but I don't really see how to fix that problem, as all the functions and classes are used in the tab_processing function. I wish that I could just run the whole thing instead of just running one function, so then maybe subprocess is the best practice here?

Not sure if it changes anything but this goes through a lot of data and so need to be pretty efficient resource-wise.

Comment: To solve your 'global pd not defined' in the tab.py, add/move the needed imports to the top, specifically import pandas as pd, may be others you also need up there such as numpy. Then in your master_processing.py, there isn't a Tab.main to call, but there is Tab.tab_processing(path) - call that, give it the path to work on, and you'll get the data back. If I were you I'd get that working with a couple of your data sources, possibly on shortened data, before attempting to run the data processing in parallel..

Comment: Oh well, that was easy, thanks!
So in that case I guess it doesn't make any sense to have the if name = main.

Comment: Have 'if name == '__main__' in the tab file? It's not needed for your new purpose, but perfectly normal to have it there, e.g. if you ever want to run just that process, or implement some tests of the tab code, then keep it.